# How do I change the radius of a circle in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry

(Using PostgreSQL 9.1, without the GIS stuff installed)

Assuming I've got a box (which should always be square):

```
> SELECT box '((0, 0), (1,1))'
"(1,1),(0,0)"
```

I can get a circle that fits inside the square:

```
> SELECT circle (box '((0, 0), (1,1))')
"<(0.5,0.5),0.707106781186548>"
```

and with a bit of messing around I can get a bigger circle:

```
> SELECT circle(center(circle(box '((0, 0), (1,1))')), radius(circle(box '((0, 0), (1,1))')) * 2)
"<(0.5,0.5),1.4142135623731>"
```

but doing that as a prepared statement means passing the square twice:

```
"SELECT circle(center(circle(?)), radius(circle(?)) * 2)
```

which isn't a deal breaker, but I feel there should be a 'better' way of doing it.

Is there a easier/better way of resizing the circle? Specifically, I want a circle with its center at the center of the box, and radius equal to half the diagonal length of the box.

(If it helps, I'm using the "Contained in or on" ('<@') operator to get the set of points within an area)

Thanks.

Comment: You won't have to pass it twice if you put box in a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would construct the statement using the SQL 'WITH' command.  You probably want something of the form:

`WITH bxx as (SELECT center(bx) as cb, length(diagonal(bx)) as lb 
     FROM (SELECT box('((0,0),(1,1))') AS bx) AS bun) 
SELECT circle(cb, lb) from bxx;`

The WITH clause generates a table to be used in the following SQL (SELECT in this case) statement.

What we do here is construct a table containing a column for the box center and one for the length of diagonal.  The subquery in the 'WITH' clause establishes the BOX as a column (bx).

SQL requires that the subquery be named, hence the 'AS bun' -- which is unused.

This construction also makes it easier to fiddle with the center and length parameters for variations of your problem.

I should also point out that in your problem statement, the first circle you create is outside the box (center in the center, but the radius is half the diagonal -- meaning the box is inscribed in the circle).  For a circle inside the box, you want to use a radius length of half the length of the sides of the square, not the diagonal.